# regular expression on date with python

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split a string with a regular expression as a parameter.
for example, an email :

```
A ten, for sure. Photos are great as well as the service! 

Sent from my iPad

On Jul 17, 2017, at 11:32 AM, Steve <photo.print@pictarine.com> wrote:

Hi Patty! 

It would really help us if you could take 10 seconds of your time to rate your experience with Walgreens Photo Print from 0-10 below
```

I want to identify the date with the regression , but it can be july, december, november etc...
But how can I identify it with several months ?

Comment: Put the months in a group,, then separate with alternations (or) like this `(Jan|Feb|Mar|..|..|..,etc) the rest of the date expression here`

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35413952/4333555