# How to extract specific date format from a plain text (python)?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all dates (in the specific date format - January 1, 2020) into the dictionary in python. My text is for example:

> "Psg January 1, 2020 hsjkfsdlkfhshdfh January 2, 1908 hdhahhajshjdjoi December 31, 2019 fafsfafagherhea"

I will then extract this into:

```py
["January 1, 2020", "January 2, 1908", "December 31, 2019"]
```

I found the method `str.split()`. No success with this.

How can I do this?

Thank you for the help!

P.S.

Actually I want to extract that dates and then convert in the format:

```
"January 1, 2020" -> "1. January 2020"
```

and then turn it back in the text.

**In the nutshell**: I want to replace some format of date in text with some other format of a date.

**Edit**:

I have made the process. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: You should do this using regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match date like month name day comma and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413746/regex-to-match-date-like-month-name-day-comma-and-year/35413952)

Comment: @User123 Please, have a look at the [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked a dozen times. Imo the best way is to use a library, e.g. [**`datefinder`**](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder):

```
import datefinder
text = "Psg January 1, 2020 hsjkfsdlkfhshdfh January 2, 1908 hdhahhajshjdjoi December 31, 2019 fafsfafagherhea"
matches = datefinder.find_dates(text)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Which yields

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
1908-01-02 00:00:00
2019-12-31 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

For this task is better to use regular expressions ([`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) module in Python).

For example ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8HFAFE/1) for explanation):

```
txt = '''Psg January 1, 2020 hsjkfsdlkfhshdfh January 2, 1908 hdhahhajshjdjoi December 31, 2019 fafsfafagherhea'''
import re

r = re.compile(r'(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)')

new_txt = r.sub(r'\2. \1 \3', txt)
print(new_txt)
```

Prints:

```
Psg 1. January 2020 hsjkfsdlkfhshdfh 2. January 1908 hdhahhajshjdjoi 31. December 2019 fafsfafagherhea
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex like will help you easily `'((?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d+,\s+\d+)'`

```
message = "Psg January 1, 2020 hsjkfsdlkfhshdfh January 2, 1908 hdhahhajshjdjoi December 31, 2019 fafsfafagherhea"
matches = re.findall(
    r'((?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d+,\s+\d+)',
    message)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Then for the date format, use `strptime` and `strftime`

```
from datetime import datetime

input_format = "%B %d, %Y" # full month name, day and year
output_format = "%d.%B %Y"
for match in matches:
    new_date = datetime.strptime(match, input_format).strftime(output_format)
    print(match, ">>", new_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function find() to research the index of any month and you can count the character to extract

Seen : https://www.journaldev.com/23666/python-string-find

Answer (score 1):

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

date_info = "Psg January 1, 2020 hsjkfsdlkfhshdfh January 2, 1908 hdhahhajshjdjoi December 31, 2019 fafsfafagherhea"

for month in months:
    while month in date_info.split():
        m = month
        day = date_info.split()[date_info.split().index(month) + 1]
        year = date_info.split()[date_info.split().index(month) + 2]
        self_str = month + " " + day + " " + year
        rep_str = day.strip(',') + ". " + month +"~ " + year
        date_info = date_info.replace(self_str, rep_str)
while '~' in date_info:
    date_info = date_info.replace("~", "")
print(date_info)
```

Comment: is this the output you were looking for ?

Comment: Thank you, but I have made it in the different way.

Answer (score 1):

Pure regex solution would be to use following regex to extract the specific date format strings from the given sentence :

`\w+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}`

Regex explanation and demo can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/lD26lD/2/).

Then use this regex in [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) function to match all occurrences of a pattern and return such occurrences.

```
import re
str = "Psg January 1, 2020 hsjkfsdlkfhshdfh January 2, 1908 hdhahhajshjdjoi December 31, 2019 fafsfafagherhea"
x = re.findall("\w+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}", str)
print(x)
```

```
Output :

['January 1, 2020', 'January 2, 1908', 'December 31, 2019']
```